# code about 404 works on one hosting provider, but not on the other

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I don't know if I can get an answer to this question without giving out all the code which is kind of long.

I'm a noob trying to understand in general.

I used a third-handed script for a full website on two of my websites that are hosted on two different webhosting providers. only php, no cms. the websites' structures and code are actually exactly the same, only the content is different.

On the first webhosting provider its working as it should/it's intended to be when it is supposed to send a 404, but on the other one it shows an error 'Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /**/**/public_html/**/header.php:1) in /home3/**/public_html/**/footer.php on line 253

Any suggestion what the problem could be, especially what the difference might be?

Answer (score 1):

**Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by** for understanding happens on code like this:

```
<html>
<body>
hello world
<?php header(...); ?>
<body>
</html>
```

Here a http-header and "hello world" is sent to the browser and then an attempt is made to send a header again. This would generate the **headers already sent** error message.

If **gzip** is activated on the web server, for example, the web server **buffers the entire output** and outputs it completely at the end. In this case the header is combined and sent as one. So gzip respectively output buffering can accept the wrong code. This could be the difference between your two web hosts.

**Tips:** You should run the header() function pretty much first in the code. Empty lines before and outside php can also become a problem.

```
[empty line]
<?php
header(...);
?><html>
<body></body>
</html>
```

The [PHP outout puffering](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.outcontrol.php) could helping in some cases to avoid this problem, too.